# Fatal Python error: Couldn't create autoTLSkey mapping with C++ binding

Tags: c++, python, binding

when trying to create a sub process from python binding, i have this error :

"Fatal Python error: Couldn't create autoTLSkey mapping"
If i just run the script from the terminal, there is no problem.
Does anyone have any informations about this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

And for others not on 2.7.2 this could also be a memory limit issue. In my uwsgi settings file I had:

```
limit-as = 512
reload-on-as = 256
reload-on-rss = 192
```

But these were too low. So if you have a similar limit then increase them.